# What the Exception? InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, asp.net

In a legacy application, we have a `SqlDataReader`.  The following field creates a `InvalidCastException` with a `bit` field.

```
public static T GetValueOrNull<T>(this IDataReader reader, string column)
{
     int ordinal;
     if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(column) && !reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal(column)))
          if(int.TryParse(reader.GetOrdinal(column).ToString(), out ordinal))
               return (T)reader.GetValue(ordinal);

      return default(T);
}
```

What is odd, is that `(T)reader.GetValue(ordinal)` does assign a valid type.  It assigns a `false`, but the error still occurs.  I'm not entirely sure why.

If I perform `GetType();` it does indeed show `Boolean` type.  I've also checked to ensure that it is threadsafe.

Comment: How do you know it returns false?

Comment: @AlexandrePepin Instead of `return` I assigned to a variable, which did show it as a `false`.

Comment: Just to verify, `reader.GetValue(ordinal) == typeof(bool)`?

Comment: @Chris `reader.GetValue(ordinal)` by default will return `object`.  Since it is retrieving from Sql.  That is why I cast to the desired type for my model.

Comment: Which statement throws the `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: @haim770 `return (T)reader.GetValue(ordinal)` is the line that will throw.

Comment: If it throws how is it evaluated to `false`?

Comment: @Greg That's just the return type of the method, the value should still be a (boxed) `bool`, which is an `object`. If `GetType()` returns `typeof(bool)` the cast will work.

Comment: Well what is the actual type of reader.GetValue(ordinal)? You should be able to see this during debugging.

Comment: What does reader.GetValue(ordinal); give you as a type?

Comment: @haim770 I pushed the line down and actually pushed directly to a variable.  Which showed the value.

Comment: @Greg ok while you have gotten the value pushed directly to a variable, what is the type?

Comment: As a side note, what's the point of doing a `ToString` and then parsing the ordinal?

Comment: @Chris `GetOrdinal` should return an `int`, however to avoid a potential exception I used a `TryParse` which requires a type of `string`.

Comment: Have you have checked that `T` is `bool`? Are you absolutely sure the exception occurs at this point and that your project has compiled correctly? Also, if `(T)reader.GetValue(ordinal)` works when you assign it to a variable, what happens if you return that variable?

Comment: @Greg `GetOrdinal` will either give you a valid ordinal integer, or throw. I don't see what possible exception you can avoid doing all that...

Comment: Do `Type t1 = typeof(T), t2 = reader.GetValue(ordinal).GetType();` before the first return, set a breakpoint and show us what you get.

Comment: I suspect OP needs to cast to bool? because his bit field is nullable, or he is using tinyint and needs to cast to byte.

Comment: @Greg call `reader.GetFieldType(ordinal)` to see what type you need to cast to. I'm fairly certain you'll see `Nullable<bool>`, `byte`, or `Nullable<byte>` returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code would fail on a the *bit field*, which would be correlated to a *boolean* was due to the inferred type.  The underlying data type wasn't `bool` but rather a `bool?`.

Once the model reflected a nullable boolean, the code worked as intended.